# Mouse Events not working while overlapping SVG lines

Tags: html, svg

I have a page like this , here I have two circles one with yellow color and one with red color , when placed simultaneously , the mouse events are not triggering means the underlying circle mouse event is hidden

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My first SVG</h1>

<svg width="100" height="100" style="position:fixed;top:50;left:40;z-index:2;">
   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" onmouseout="evt.target.setAttribute('opacity','1');" onmouseover="evt.target.setAttribute('opacity','0.5');" onclick="alert('yellow clicked')"/>
   Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg> 

<svg width="100" height="100" style="position:fixed;top:50;left:40;z-index:1;">
   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="brown" onmouseout="evt.target.setAttribute('opacity','1');" onmouseover="evt.target.setAttribute('opacity','0.5');" onclick="alert('red clicked')"/>
   Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The svg elements have an attribute `pointer-events`, that controls whether an event is fired relating to that element. e.g. If you set `pointer-events="none"` on your top circle, it becomes transparent, so the event can occur at the bottom circle

```
<svg id="mySVG" width="400" height="400">
<circle onclick=alert() id=bottomCircle cx=200 cy=200 r=150 fill=red />
<circle pointer-events="none" id=topCircle cx=200 cy=200 r=130 fill=blue />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked now

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My first SVG</h1>

<svg>
<svg width="100" height="100" style="position:fixed;top:50;left:40;z-index:2;">
   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" onmouseout="evt.target.setAttribute('opacity','1');" onmouseover="evt.target.setAttribute('opacity','0.5');" onclick="alert('yellow clicked')"/>
   Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg> 

<svg width="100" height="100" style="position:fixed;top:50;left:40;z-index:1;">
   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="brown" onmouseout="evt.target.setAttribute('opacity','1');" onmouseover="evt.target.setAttribute('opacity','0.5');" onclick="alert('red clicked')"/>
   Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg> 
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```